# Add swipe to only one plugin j.Query 1.6.1

Tags: jquery, mobile

The outline:

I am using two j.Query plugins on a website. I need to add a swipe left and right as functions to one of them. I have done it successfully with j.Query Mobile latest versions below:

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-
   1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

All works fine only in an isolated code, outside the other plugin.

The problem:

Unfortunately the other plugin just does not work with any j.Query version higher than j.Query-1.6.1 and when I include higher versions mentioned above, the other plugin stops working properly.

I could not find a j.Query Mobile compatible with 1.6.1 so that two plugins could work on the same version. Is there a compatible j.Query Mobile version available so that I could add my swiping like so:

```
   function swiping(){

  $(function(){

  var anim = $('div#carousel');
  $(anim).on( "swipeleft", swiper );
  $(anim).on( "swiperight", swiper1 );

  function swiper(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#carousel').roundabout('animateToNextChild', showCaption);

    }

   function swiper1(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#carousel').roundabout('animateToPreviousChild', showCaption);

    }
    });

    }
```

If not, how do I add swipe (left and write) for mobile in such a way that the two plugins could run on the same j.Query 1.6.1. Both do run fine but without the swipe, which I need to add to only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep everything within the same version of j.Query and add swipe for mobile to one plugin, I had to change the way I wrote my functions, I followed the example below plus added an older version of j.Query mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'
  src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript'
  src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
<style type='text/css'>
.add-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
function bindEvent(element) {
    element.bind('tap taphold swipe swiperight swipeleft', function(event, ui) {
       alert('Event: '+event.type); 
    });
}
bindEvent($('#display-event'));
});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div id="display-event" class="add-border">
        <p>Tap, TapHold (for 1 second), Swipe, SwipeRight or SwipeLeft</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```